# How to call a function from one class in a different class

Tags: c++, function, class, header-files, virtual-functions

I am making a program that is formed by 2 header files. One is called `contact.h`, which contains a `class Contact` with 2 children classes; email and phone number. Both of the children classes have a function `set_contact()` and `print()`.

The other header file is called `Person.h` and contains a class `Person`. A function `void print();` is supposed to use the print function for both email and phone number from the `contact` class.

How can I implement those functions inside of the `print()` function for class `Person`?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please *show it*. Preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It sounds like instance of class `Contact` should be defined as member of class `Person` or vise verse. But regarding your question, you can just pass `Contact` instance as argument of `Person::print()` method

Comment: Another option, and depending on your problem, probably `Person` should have two members `PhoneNumber m_phone` and `Email m_email` (assuming those are the names of the `Contact` subclasses). From here it is straightforward to use them in the `print` method since they are member of the class.